# while importing project getting out of memory error

Tags: intellij-idea

while importing the project into intellij i am getting below error

```
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
Read Gradle's configuration guide
Read about Java's heap size
```

I have tried to solve by increasing heap size,
i.e xmx and xms but still not working